# UWP how to get text from RichEditBox to RichTextBlock

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, richtextblock, richeditbox

If i have RichEditBox what contains some text how could i get all of that text and move it to RichTextBlock?

Example text below:

[image: RichEditBox]

Closest what i have got looks like following

[image]

I have used Microsoft own [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) in this project. I would like also keep text formatting while getting text from the RichEditBox. Is this kind of thing even possible to do?

Comment: Hi there, Can you give us an example of your code in this issue?

Comment: @StuiterSlurf my code is almost same as https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing/cs but do you want more specific example?

Comment: Did you try the Document property? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.document#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_RichEditBox_Document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i have RichEditBox what contains some text how could i get all of that text and move it to RichTextBlock?

You could get Text from `RichEditBox` with [`ITextDocument.GetText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.gettext) method. And the output string could contain rft format depend on which `TextGetOption` you used.

But, the rtf string could not be loaded with `RichTextBlock`, it does not support RTF. it only [support](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4d9cfe69-ce9e-416d-bcde-ad0c99ee7180/u81how-to-get-and-set-the-rtf-text-in-richtextblock-in-winrt?forum=wpdevelop) the formatting with xaml Block elements.

Currently there is a workaround that you could convert your rft string to html and display the content with UWP [`WebView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview). For more you could refer this [case reply](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/096f87bd-3c47-4e68-8b47-b8e36d0ff73c/cuwp-how-to-convert-rtf-string-including-image-into-html-string-and-vice-versa?forum=wpdevelop) in msdn.